# Chrome Redux DevTools crashes when Route changes

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

After updating NgRx to 6.1.0 from 4 I am seeing an issue with Redux DevTools Extension. It crashes every time the route changes.

I added the serializer
[link](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/router-store/api.md#custom-router-state-serializer)
that the documentation recommended but the problem still exists

I had to change the way CustomSerializer is being provided according to this article
[link](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/ngrx-tutorial-add-router-info-to-state/)
because my IDE was showing an error if I tried to implement exactly the way the documentation showed

I also tried with without storeFreeze and omitted metaReducer object inside StoreModule.forRoot() but still the same issue

```
// reducers/index.ts
import { ActionReducerMap, MetaReducer } from '@ngrx/store';
import { storeFreeze } from 'ngrx-store-freeze';
import { Params, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

import {
  routerReducer,
  RouterReducerState,
  RouterStateSerializer
} from '@ngrx/router-store';

export interface RouterStateUrl {
  url: string;
  params: Params;
  queryParams: Params;
}

@Injectable()
export class CustomSerializer implements RouterStateSerializer<RouterStateUrl> {
  serialize(routerState: RouterStateSnapshot): RouterStateUrl {
    let route = routerState.root;

    while (route.firstChild) {
      route = route.firstChild;
    }

    const {
      url,
      root: { queryParams }
    } = routerState;
    const { params } = route;

    // Only return an object including the URL, params and query params
    // instead of the entire snapshot
    return { url, params, queryParams };
  }
}

export interface State {
  router: RouterReducerState<RouterStateUrl>;
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<State> = {
  router: routerReducer
};

export const metaReducers: Array<MetaReducer<State>> = environment.environment !== EnvironmentEnum.PRODUCTION ? [storeFreeze] : [];


// app-routing.module.ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes,
      { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})


// app.module.ts
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { metaReducers, reducers, State } from './reducers';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    //Other imports
    AppRoutingModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { metaReducers }),
    StoreRouterConnectingModule,
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument(),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([sharedEffects.UserEffects])
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: RouterStateSerializer,
      useClass: CustomSerializer
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: I have the same problem as you Nijat. This seems to be one of those issues where I spend several days googling a problem and pulling stuff out of code to nail down the problem. You'd assume after following pro tutorials and documentation carefully that everything would go to plan... Sorry I can't be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Nijat. I've been messing around with my setup and have got it working without crashing dev-tools. In my imports in app.module.ts I now have the following:

```
imports: [
StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot({
  serializer: CustomSerializer,
}),

StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
  maxAge: 25, // Retains last 25 states
  logOnly: environment.production, // Restrict extension to log-only mode
}),
]
```

I also removed it from the 'providers' array in the app module. I also don't have the serializer marked as @Injectable.

Hopefully this might help you.

Cheers
MP